# searching for occurrences in access database

Tags: python, ms-access

I am trying to search in access database for some occurrence, but I found that my code miss somes when it made a search.
I found that he miss the second occurence when it found the first one.

Example: if I have the following and I am looking for T300 and I have this structure:

T200

T300

T300

it will catch first T300 and pass the second T300

```
enter code here
import csv
import pyodbc
from xml.dom import minidom


# *************************************

def DBAccess (Term):
 MDB = 'c:/test/mydb.mdb'
 DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
 PWD = ''

 conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRV,MDB,PWD))
 curs = conn.cursor()


 curs.execute("select * from gdo_segment")
 rows = curs.fetchall()
 for row in rows:
     T = 'T' + str(row.troncon) + '_' + row.noeud1 + '-' + row.noeud2
     if (T == Term ):
         print T


 curs.close()
 conn.close()


#*************************************

def findTerminal():

 xmldoc = minidom.parse('c:\\test\mydoc.xml')
 #printing the number of blocs in my xml file
 itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ACLineSegment') 

 for item in itemlist:
     found = False
     for child in item.childNodes:
        if child.nodeName == 'Terminal':
            found = True
     if not found:
         Term = item.getAttribute('Name')
         DBAccess (Term)        




#***********************************



findTerminal()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is finding the last item, and this would be because of your code indenting. Correct indenting is essential in Python. [the docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html)

Currently, your `if` statement only applies after all the looping has completed, so will only check the last value of T.

```
def DBAccess (Term):
    MDB = 'c:/test/gdomt.mdb'
    DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
    PWD = ''

    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRV,MDB,PWD))
    curs = conn.cursor()


    curs.execute("select * from gdo_segment")
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        T = 'T' + str(row.troncon) + '_' + row.noeud1 + '-' + row.noeud2
        if (T == Term ):
            print T

    curs.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: You could add your revised code to the bottom of your first post. You need to indent every line a further four spaces for it to display accurately in the post. Highlight all the code and click the code-tag button. However, you question states that you are looking for T300, but this doesn't match your code, which includes an underscore, a hyphen and three fields.

Comment: i put all my code like it's with me(it's above in my first comment)